# Timing command is obsolete

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, timing

I am on 
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

When I submit

```
Timing start
```

command, I get

```
Timing command is obsolete.
```

I searched a lot but did not find a reason why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Tested in Oracle SQL Developer 17.2.0.188

I understand it is an issue of Oracle SQL Developer.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: This is a client command. SQL\*Plus still seems happy with it; SQL Developer (and SQLcl) say it's obsolete. All three still support `set timing on`, which isn't quite the same but might do what you need. And in SQL Developer you can see the total time in the script output or query results window.

Comment: So is this a question about SQL Developer specifically? If so, please tag it and mention the version. (I don't normally use SQL Developer but I've just checked in 4.2 and it does print the message `Timing command is obsolete.`) If you want to know why the SQL Developer product team decided to stop supporting this feature, perhaps Jeff Smith will reply with their thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that because we chose to NOT support that SQL*Plus feature when building [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html), which is also the code that SQL Developer uses for running scripts.

You can use SET TIMING ON and SET TIMING OFF instead.

We wanted to build a modern command line interface for the Oracle Database, that took the things people liked about SQL*Plus AND SQL Developer - and also add things that just made sense (a better describe - INFO - automatic output formatting, DDL command, etc.)

This is one of the thing we did not see customers using in the wild. So it had very low priority when it came to duplicating SQL*Plus features. So low in fact, we just dropped it.

Answer (score 2):

TIMING in SQLPlus has a resolution of 10ms. If you use `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` values you get a resolution of up to 1 Nanosecond. Build your own timer with `SYSTIMESTAMP`